# Vba code to Track Changes in Excel only when cell value is updated. Don't run the code if row is added or deleted

Tags: excel

Below is the code which tracks changes while updating cell value in excel sheet and throughs error when row is added or deleted.

I need modification as where if row is deleted or added then do nothing (code should not run)

Could anyone help here??

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    For Each j In Target
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim ws2 As Worksheet
        Dim NextRow As Long
        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Change Log") 'Sheet name where I am tracking the changes
        NextRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Dim CellAdd As String

        CellAdd = j.Address
        Dim sht As String
        sht = ActiveSheet.Name
        Dim newValue As String
        newValue = j.Value
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Undo
        oldValue = j.Value
        Application.Undo
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        ws2.Cells(NextRow, 1) = sht & " " & "-" & " " & CellAdd & _ 
            " was changed to '" & newValue & "' from '" & _
            oldValue & "' by " & Environ("username") & " " & _
            "on" & " " & Format(Now(), "M-DD- YYYY H:MM:ss")
    Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: A workaround can be if tirst check if the involved target is only one cell. But if  only a cell is deleted or inserted there can be the same issue.

Comment: You would have to track the number of rows with data separatly - on worksheet module level. But this will become tricky if you dont have a continous data range

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works for you but in my short testing it only wrote changes to the Change Log if it wasn't a row addition/deletion. The `Worksheet_Activate` is to give it an initial value.

Do note: lRow is based on A-column, adjust it accordingly. If cells are shifted upwards not-including this lRow-check-column, there'd be an issue of course but you mentioned rows (not cell shifting).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    amtRows = Me.Range("A" & Me.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = Me.Range("A" & Me.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If lRow <> amtRows Then
        Debug.Print "Rows changed"
        amtRows = lRow
    Else
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim ws2 As Worksheet
        Dim NextRow As Long, j As Range
        Dim CellAdd As String, newValue As String, sht As String, oldValue As String
        
        For Each j In Target
            Set wb = ThisWorkbook
            Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Change Log") 'Sheet name where i am tracking the changes"
            NextRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            
            CellAdd = j.Address
            sht = ActiveSheet.Name
            newValue = j.Value
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Application.Undo
            oldValue = j.Value
            Application.Undo
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            ws2.Cells(NextRow, 1) = sht & " " & "- " & " " & CellAdd & " was changed to '" & _
            newValue & "' from '" & oldValue & "' by " & Environ("username") & " " & _
            "on" & " " & Format(Now(), "M-DD-YYYY H: MM: ss ")
        Next j

    End If
End Sub
```